# stm32 cubeIDE DMA DAC noise on DAC output

Tags: stm32, wav, noise, dma, stm32cubeide

Im running a stm32 L432KC nucleo with the following settings.

clk = 80 Mhz
Spi to to sd card module
Prescaler 2
Counter period 1813
buffer size 500

Half buffering to play .wav music file at a freq of 22050 hz. 8bit mono

Im getting strange noise from the DAC output. And my clk seems to be off even though ive set it up in the correct way.

I have tried switching mcu, adjusting clk, 5 different amp circuits, code seems to be fine.
When playing a 440hz sinewave i get the following output[oscillocope on DAC1 output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fV28q.jpg)

[image]

Comment: You never showed us your code, but I suspect it is not "fine".

Comment: As @pmacfarlane wrote your code is definitely not right :)

Comment: It turned out to be a problem with two sources. The first being me measuring on the wrong pin. And the second i needed a capacitor between the input of the amp and output from DAC. That solved all issues :D But most importantly, the code was ok ;)